# Why isn't the StringBuilder class inherited from Stream?

Tags: c#, stream, stringbuilder

I'm just curious about this.  It strikes me that the behavior of a StringBuilder is functionally (if not technically) the same as a Stream -- it's a bin of data to which other data can be added.

Again, just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stream is an input and output of *binary* data.

StringBuilder is means of building up *text* data.

Beyond that, there's the issue of state - a StringBuilder just has the current value, with no idea of "position". It allows you to access and mutate data anywhere within it. A stream, on the other hand, is logically a potentially infinite stream of data, with a cursor somewhere in the middle to say where you've got to. You generally just read/write forwards, with Seek/Position to skip to a specific part of the data stream.

Try to imagine implementing the Stream API with StringBuilder... it just doesn't fit. You could *sort* of do it, but you'd end up with StringReader and StringWriter, basically.

Answer (score 10):

`StringBuilder` has more than just Append functions.  It also has insert functions which is unnatural for a stream.  Use the `StringWriter` class if you want a stream that wraps a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 6):

A stream normally refers to an external input/output source (file, network). StringBuilder has no such characteristic.

Comment: +1 ... I was in the process of writing an answer eerily similar to this... :D

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not really a stream.  It's more of a buffer that grows.

Answer (score 1):

While both can have data added to them, the functionality as a whole is different.

A Stream is for inputting or outputting data from/to some source, not for building something.  StringBuilder does not need functionality that Stream provides, like Buffering, etc to build a resource.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand you will find the classes **StringReader**/**Writer** in System.IO. The **StringWriter** e.g. implements **TextWriter** against an underlying **StringBuilder**.

Personally I've never used it but if you have a text file writing routine you could make it work against a **TextWriter**. Then in your test, instead of instantiating a **StreamWriter** you instantiate a **StringWriter** and you could then check what was written by looking at the underlying **StringBuilder**.

Now I'm dizzy...